# Display folders and files in a GUI using python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I have to create a program that lists selected folders in my computer, and then if the user clicks on the folder name, the list of files in the folder will pop out.

The folder names must be in button form. I have a non gui program for listing the folders and files that I want and I want these to be displayed in a GUI and this where I am stuck. Is there a module in python that lets you create a GUI to display folders and files in them?

Comment: [Have you even tried searching](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)?

Answer (score 0):

In python, you have the common GUI libraries like PyGtk (3 or 2) or PyQt (4 or 5).

http://www.pygtk.org/
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt

Those integrate already what you need to provide a way to browse your files in your system (no need to recreate that, the Widgets and Dialogs already exist).